# Bat read text obtain variable

Tags: batch-file, user-input

I found help on this topic.  User: Hackoo had a great piece of code.  I ran it on a text file, and it created 5 different variables as expected.  It worked perfect.  I would like to know how to prompt the user to select which variable they would like to keep.  Then take there input and place it into a separate text file.  Is that possible?  Here is the code which works to obtain the variables.

```sh
@echo off
set "File2Read=file.txt"
If Not Exist "%File2Read%" (Goto :Error)
rem This will read a file into an array of variables and populate it 
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do (
set /a count+=1
set "Line[!count!]=%%a"
)
 rem Display array elements
 For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
 echo "Var%%i" is assigned to ==^> "!Line[%%i]!"
 )
 pause>nul
 Exit
 ::***************************************************
 :Error
 cls & Color 4C
 echo(
 echo   The file "%File2Read%" dos not exist !
 Pause>nul
 exit /b
 ::***************************************************
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, in fact it could be done with some basic research. Your question is also to vague. Back to what @Compo said you don't actually have a problem, just an idea. Please refine your question with some code that you would like to EDIT and I would be more than happy to answer.

Comment: (file.txt) contains - jr high,freshman,softmore,jr,senior.  

currently when I run the code, it reads the file and returns each line as. - [var1] jr high,[var2] freshman,[var3] softmore,[var4] jr,[var5] senior

But it doesnt let me select which variable to keep.  I would like it to ask me which one i would like to keep.  


I would like to be able to select one of these varibales and place it into file (file2.txt).  Thank You!!

Comment: Don't put additional/updated information into coments, [edit] your question instead. Also without any coding attempts on your input issue this is still **off topic**. Hint view online help on [set /p](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)